# Java: parse ISO_DATE / ISO_OFFSET_DATE

Tags: java, date, iso, java-time, timezone-offset

For a REST web service, I need to return **dates (no time) with a time zone**.

Apparently there is no such thing as a `ZonedDate` in Java (only `LocalDate` and `ZonedDateTime`), so I'm using `ZonedDateTime` as a fallback.

When converting those dates to JSON, I use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE` to format the date, which works really well:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE;
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
String formatted = dateTime.format(formatter);
```

> 2018-04-19+02:00

However, attempting to parse back such a date with...

```
ZonedDateTime parsed = ZonedDateTime.parse(formatted, formatter);
```

... results in an Exception:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-04-19+02:00' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {OffsetSeconds=7200},ISO resolved to 2018-04-19 of type java.time.format.Parsed

I also tried `ISO_DATE` and ran into the same problem.

How can I parse such a zoned date back? 
Or is there any other type (within the Java Time API) I'm supposed to use for zoned dates?

Comment: FYI, `+02:00` is a mere [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), not a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). A time zone [has a name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) such as `Europe/Zurich`, and keeps a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution (using `TemporalQueries`): 
parse the date and zone separately, and restore the zoned date using that information:

```
LocalDate date = formatter.parse(formatted, TemporalQueries.localDate());
ZoneId zone = formatter.parse(formatted, TemporalQueries.zone());
ZonedDateTime restored = date.atStartOfDay(zone);
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `ZonedDateTime` needs all the date and time fields to be built (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, nanosecond), but the formatter `ISO_OFFSET_DATE` produces a string without the time part.

When parsing it back, there are no time-related fields (hours, minutes, seconds) and you get a `DateTimeParseException`.

One alternative to parse it is to use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and define default values for the time fields. As you used `atStartOfDay` in your answer, I'm assuming you want midnight, so you can do the following:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date and offset
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE)
    // default values for hour and minute
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
    .toFormatter();
ZonedDateTime parsed = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-04-19+02:00", fmt); // 2018-04-19T00:00+02:00
```

---

[Your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49922704) also works fine, but the only problem is that you're parsing the input **twice** (each call to `formatter.parse` will parse the input again). A better alternative is to use the `parse` method without a temporal query (parse only once), and then use the parsed object to get the information you need.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE;
// parse input
TemporalAccessor parsed = formatter.parse("2018-04-19+02:00");

// get data from the parsed object
LocalDate date = LocalDate.from(parsed);
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.from(parsed);
ZonedDateTime restored = date.atStartOfDay(zone); // 2018-04-19T00:00+02:00
```

With this solution, the input is parsed only once.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

Use a time zone (`continent/region`) rather than a mere offset-from-UTC (hours-minutes-seconds). For any particular zone, the offset is likely to change over time.

Combine the two to determine a moment.

```
LocalDate.parse(
  "2018-04-19"
)
.atStartOfDay( 
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/Zurich" ) 
) // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
```

> 2018-04-19T00:00+02:00[Europe/Zurich]

From your REST service, either:

- Return the date and zone separately (either with a delimiter or as XML/JSON), or,
- Return the start of day as that is likely the intended outcome of a date with a time zone.

## Separate your text inputs

The solution in the [Answer by Walser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49922704/642706) is effectively treating the string input as a pair of string inputs. First the date-only part is extracted and parsed. Second, the offset-from-UTC part is extracted and parsed. So, the input is parsed twice, each time ignoring the opposite half of the string.

I suggest you make this practice explicit. Track the date as one piece of text, track the offset (or, better, a time zone) as another piece of text. As the code in that other Answer demonstrates, there is no real meaning to a date with zone until you take the next step of determining an actual moment such as the start of day.

```
String inputDate = "2018-04-19" ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( inputDate ) ;

String inputOffset = "+02:00" ;
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of( inputOffset) ;

OffsetTime ot = OffsetTime.of( LocalTime.MIN , offset ) ; 
OffsetDateTime odt = ld.atTime( ot ) ;  // Use `OffsetDateTime` & `ZoneOffset` when given a offset-from-UTC. Use `ZonedDateTime` and `ZoneId` when given a time zone rather than a mere offset.
```

> odt.toString(): 2018-04-19T00:00+02:00

As you can see, the code is simple, and your intent is obvious.

And no need to bother with any `DateTimeFormatter` object nor formatting patterns. Those inputs conform with ISO 8601 standard formats. The *java.time* classes use those standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

## Offset versus Zone

As for applying the date and offset to get a moment, you are conflating a [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) with a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). An offset is simply a number of hours, minutes, and seconds. No more, no less. In contrast, a time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes in offset used by the people of a particular region.

In other words, the `+02:00` happens to be used by many time zones on many dates. But in a particular zone, such as `Europe/Zurich`, other offsets may be used on other dates. For example, adopting the silliness of Daylight Saving Time (DST) means a zone will be spending half the year with one offset and the other half with a different offset.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Zurich" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2018-04-19T00:00+02:00[Europe/Zurich]

So I suggest you track two strings of input:

- Date-only (`LocalDate`): YYYY-MM-DD such as `2018-04-19`
- Proper time zone name (`ZoneId`): continent/region such as `Europe/Zurich`

Combine.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = 
    LocalDate.parse( inputDate )
             .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( inputZone ) ) 
;
```

Note: The `ZonedDateTime::toString` method generates a String in a format that wisely extends the standard ISO 8601 format by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets. This rectifies a huge oversight made by the otherwise well-designed standard. But you can only return such a string by your REST service if you know your clients can consume it.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).